# Git rollback to previous commit on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I need to rollback the `[remote "origin"]` without touching the `[remote "heroku"]`. They are both live sites on heroku.  Also, I'm not sure if this file (`.git/config`) is correct. Please help.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:tidelake/site.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[prompt]
    showinfo = true
[remote "heroku"]
    url = https://git.heroku.com/site-new.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

Comment: If you have deployed the previous commit before, you can just go to heroku `activity` tab and click `roll back to here` next to the last deployment. However, your `origin` remote is not a heroku repo, so most likely you are using CI to deploy to staging environment, is it correct?

Comment: `git push heroku master` somehow deploys both sites. I don't know how to fix that either.

Comment: Maybe "origin" is using github integration [Check here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration)